# Why is Scrapy executed even if the item pipeline setting is not enough?

Tags: scrapy

In Scrapy, I was trying to incorporate the ImagesPipeline and run it, but it took me a while to notice the spelling mistakes in the settings. (It expects "IMAGES_STORE" but I typed to "IMAEGS_STORE"). I found that the ImagesPipeline was not loaded in the debug log, but the cause was not immediately understood. It is mysterious why it will not cause an error when running Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

It did not throw error because you can put your custom settings in `settings.py` of your choice.

So Scrapy thought that `IMAEGS_STORE` was some your custom variable and that maybe used somewhere.

You can put `Keisuke_URAGO=123` in `settings.py` and scrapy will not throw error. This is what `settings.py` is meant to be.

Comment: My opinion in this case was that I wanted to know quickly why the ImagesPipeline was not loaded. (In this case there is no IMAGES_STORE.)